# wp_enqueue_style not working as expected

Tags: wordpress, styles

So I'm trying to migrate my static site into a WordPress one and having trouble getting the styles and scripts to load properly.

Here is my functions.php

```
<?php
function my_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . 'css/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all');
}

add_action ('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles');
?>
```

My style.css is within a folder named css that's within the themes folder itself. Anyone have any idea why this wouldn't load the stylesheet as expected?

Answer (score 0):

All your missing is the slash before css. Best of luck!

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css', false, '1.0', 'all');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'thene_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

function theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('parent-style') );
}
?>
```